# Error using Container Class

Tags: c#, class

The Class that is using the container is throwing an error on AmountList and PGRow that says `AmountList is inaccessible due to its protection level`

The Code

```
public virtual ActionResult getAjaxPGs(string SP = null, string PG = null)
{

    if (SP != null)
    {

        Container container = new Container();
        var PGList = from x in db.PG_mapping
                     where x.PG_SUB_PROGRAM == SP 
                     select x;

        container.PARow = PGList.Select(x => new { x.PG }).Distinct().ToArray();

       container.AmountList = from x in db.Spend_Web
                        where x.PG == PG
                        group x by new { x.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD, x.PG, x.Amount } into pggroup
                        select new { accounting_period = pggroup.Key.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD, amount = pggroup.Sum(x => x.Amount) };

      return Json(container, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return View();
}

public class Container
{
    Array PARow;
    Array AmountList;

}
```

I tried making the class public, do I have to do something else to make the class accessible to `getAjaxPGs`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [class members are `private`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx) - the are only accessible to the class itself.

You need to declare them as public if you want to access them from outside the class (or `internal` if the code that requires access only ever exists in the same assembly).

```
public class Container
{
    public Array PARow;
    public Array AmountList;
}
```

Note: the above (public access to fields) is considered bad practice - you should be using properties for this.

```
public class Container
{
    public Array PARow {get; set;}
    public Array AmountList {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Oded that worked to great get rid of the container error but now I have an error on the select line for AmountList(red squiggle under select...Error 10 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Array'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)) Any ideas?

Comment: @Goldentp - Don't use `Array` as a type. Don't use anonymous types either - make classes for the data you want.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but I don't think I understand. Am I using the array as a type? Should I make classes for x.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD, x.PG, x.Amount?

Comment: @Goldentp - In `Container`, both `PARow` and `AmountList` are `Array` - this really is not a good type for these. You should probably be using a generic `List<T>` or something for them. In your LINQ query, you have a `select` clause creating an anonymous type for `accounting period` and `amount` - these should probably be a _single_ type for both.

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense you rock!